# Position an element according to browser size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I'm attempting to position an image onto a larger image. So far I am doing this according to the padding left and padding top. More specifically, I am using the following method to get the padding left and padding top:

```
function getOffsetRect(elem) {
    // (1)
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect()

    var body = document.body
    var docElem = document.documentElement

    // (2)
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop
    var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft

    // (3)
    var clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0
    var clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0

    // (4)
    var top  = box.top +  scrollTop - clientTop
    var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft

    return { top: Math.round(top), left: Math.round(left) }
}
```

This works fine. I am getting the exact position of the top left corner of my image and when I position a div on it, such as

`$("#testDiv").css({top: element.top, left: element.left, position: 'absolute'});`

it is positioned in the exact location. My problem is that when I use a larger monitor, or resize the window, then the larger image that im positioning the smaller image on becomes smaller or bigger and therefore, the original padding top and padding bottom of where the smaller images should be positioned becomes misleading. How could I adjust the position for different monitor sizes/window resizing to get it in the location it belongs?

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest to do using CSS Media Queries. W3 Schools has a good page on them so that you can get a hang of them really easily. I'd recommend checking them out and responsive design will become a breeze.

Comment: I am currently using uikit which is a responsive framework, when I resize the page the larger image resizes according to the responsiveness. However, the smaller images that I had positioned on top of the larger image are moved to weird places. No longer in their correct position on top of the larger image. Is there a way to make the smaller images responsive with the larger one?

Comment: Do you have the CSS for the project? If you put the large image inside of a div and set the div width to X% and then the image width to 100% it should resize with the image. If you then put the inner image inside of another div and set that width to whatever width you want it to be, and make the image inside of that's width 100%, the image will resize with that div. The first div will resize with the page, and the second div (The one inside of the first div) will resize based on the size of the first div.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call this method again (and then apply the new values to your top-level image's location) when the window is resized.

You can do this by adding an event listener (although you would want the second argument to be a method that calls getOffsetRect, then applies the returned value to your existing image):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', getOffsetRect(elem));
```